# How to secure communication between client and server in TCP

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, encryption

We have a TCP server with multiple client sockets connecting to it.We want to secure communication between the client sockets and server such that every message is validated before performing what it is intended to do.

We do not want to change the entire structure of the messages hence we do not intend to use encryption algorithms like AES, DES, etc. We want to add an additional parameter to every message such that this parameter must be validated with a secret key before further processing

example : 
The message : "aa,1234,send"
encrypted message must be like : "aa,1234,send,qwwdd83141dw23"

And this must be encrypted and decrypted using a secret key

Can you suggest some methods to achieve this

Comment: You seem to be confusing encryption with signing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use TLS?  Given your unnecessarily strict requirements, the only thing you could use would be an HMAC (unless you correctly consider RSA as a cryptosystem and not just an encryption algorithm).